# Create a different directory other than res/values/styles.xml to define styles

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, android-styles

As I asked in the title, is there any way to do so?
Now, when I put all styles into one file it looks a little crowded, I would like to separate styles.

For example:

```
res/values/styles_for_main_screen
res/values/styles_for_set_screen
```

And then in main_screen layout

```
<TextView
     style="@styles_for_main_screen/text_view_custom_style">
</TextView>
```

This example obviously doesn't work, but it shows what I'd like to achieve.

I read in every tutorial that we need to put our custom styles into `styles.xml` file, but I wonder if there is a possibility to diversify styles in few xml files?

Every question I read was something like "how to do .... in styles.xml".
I can't find question similar to mine.

Example how it should be done, thanks @Frank N. Stein for the answer:

This how looks my custom xml `res/values/styles_for_main_screen`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="custom_back">
        <item name="android:background">#E81C1C</item>
        <item name="android:text">whatr</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and then to retrieve this style I just write:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/custom_back"
        />
```

so the convention looks like:

```
style="@(what I want to retrieve)/(name of style)"
```

from the [android developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.htm)

> In XML: @[package:]style/style_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your style files whatever you want (if you respect the naming conventions and you put them all in the values folder/s), as you do with strings and colors.

Therefore, YES! You can have multiple ones, if so you desire.

Obviously, you will NOT specify the path to each file.
Referencing the style/s by using `R.style.your_new_style` is enough.

Comment: You're right, I just tried to do it in wrong way, I add how it should be written in my question

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, android scans the files found int the /values directory by reading their content. For styles, every `<style name="styleName"  > ... </style>` will be parser and a style object reference will be created.

Then, as Frank said, Yes. You can use whatever file name to write your custom styles.